# Is it safe to upgrade all outdated port when upgrading from Snow Leopard to Lion?

Tags: macos, open-source

My Mac running Snow Leopard has several MacPorts based open source software packages installed. Upon the upgrade to Lion, all my ports are listed as outdated.

It's safe to upgrade them en masse?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[macports.org](http://macports.org) currently says:
"Note for Lion users: There is no official release supporting Mac OS X 10.7 yet, but you can test the [MacPorts 2.0.0 release candidate](https://distfiles.macports.org/MacPorts/testing/) if you like."

I usually don't upgrade to a new major version of OS X until MacPorts has released their first official support for it.

I agree with Jerry Jacobs that you should probably back up your `/opt` hierarchy before attempting. Then you could try doing `sudo port selfupdate` to see if that upgrades you from 1.9.2 (or whatever) to the 2.0.0 release candidate.  If it does, then you can try `sudo upgrade outdated`.

I wouldn't try doing a `sudo upgrade outdated` on Lion without at least being on the 2.0.0 release candidate of MacPorts.

Comment: You also need to make sure that you have the latest Xcode installed on Lion, otherwise MacPorts will fail to build.  This is mentioned in [MacPorts FAQ](https://trac.macports.org/wiki/FAQ).

Answer (score 1):

The best thing you can do is to copy the /opt/local directory to a other directory, and then upgrade everything you installed with macports. If it fails you still have your old ports in the backup directory.

Answer (score 0):

I just upgraded to Lion yesterday. Port 1.9 stopped working until I upgraded Xcode to the newest version (4.1). After I upgraded Xcode, port (1.9) started working again.